# How to use a simple batch file to unzip & overwrite existing file

Tags: windows, batch-file, unzip

I'm trying to use a simple batch file to unzip and overwrite an existing file. Can anyone tell me the correct parameter to use to automatically overwrite without having to intervene please?

The unzip.bat batch file contains:

```
unzip "G:\Extracts\report.zip" "G:\Extracts\report\"
```

This works fine except that it asks me to "Replace the file in the destination?"

Comment: Can not you read unzip's output without any parameters ?

Comment: I suggest reading the documentation of `unzip` rather than asking us to do that...

Comment: Usually you can get the answers to these types of questions by using the `/?` argument on the command in question.  `unzip /?` probably prints the usage, including the answer to the question.

Answer (score 10):

Unzip command has `-o` option, which forces file overwrite. Your batch file should look like this:

```
unzip -o "G:\Extracts\report.zip" -d "G:\Extracts\report\"
```

Optionally, you can add `-q` for quiet mode.

Comment: I have tried both of these: 

unzip -o "G:\Extracts\report.zip" -d "G:\Extracts\report\"    

unzip -o -q "G:\Extracts\report.zip" -d "G:\Extracts\report\" 

... and Windows still prompts to "Replace existing files?"

Comment: That's strange. Try executing command from console instead of batch file. Also, run unzip without any parameter to see all available options.

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to get this to work.

Instead I used 7zip command line as follows:

Copied 7z.exe to the folder where my .bat file was placed.

Made a .bat file as follows:
7z x report.zip -o"G:\Extracts\report" -aoa

This unzipped and replaced existing files.